# Selecting date formats for aggregate calculations from database with Django

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, django-models

I would like to do aggregate calculations based on month for a datetime field.

I am currently using the extra() function to format the date like:

```
...extra(select="strftime('column', '%m/%Y') as t").values('t').annotate(SUM(foo))
```

and it works great for sqlite3.

In sqlite3 I can use strftime(), but that doesn't work with MySQL.
In MySQL I can use date_format(), but that doesn't work with sqlite3.

How can I rewrite this to work for both database types?

Most of the developers simply use sqlite3 on their dev machines, and MySQL is used on the prod server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following in your MySQL database, to create a forwarding function.

```
delimiter //

create function strftime ( d date, format varchar(255) )   
   RETURNS varchar(64)
   LANGUAGE SQL
   DETERMINISTIC
   COMMENT 'synonym for date_format'
   return date_format(d, format) ;
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't quite got that to work yet.  Where can I read more about custom MySQL functions?  I looked here, but didn't find much: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html

Comment: Got it working. In your example, the params for the custom function need to be ordered like: param_name data_type.

So it should say: create function strftime(d datetime, format varchar(255))

Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: Yeah, I whip back and forth between C/C++/Java's type identifier and SQL's identifier type. I guess I got whiplash. Or lashwhip.

Comment: Oh, if it worked, I'd appreciate an upmod or accepted answer, or both. Thanks.