# Django-MySQL is unable to recognise model.column in queryset extra?

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I have SQLite and MySQL installed on my local and development machine respectively. Following is working fine on my local machine(with SQLite):

```
select_single = {'date': "strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d',projectName_Modelname.created)"}
queryset.extra(select=select_single)
```

But since `strftime` doesn't work with MySQL([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361301/1987469)), I tried using `DATE_FORMAT()` as suggested in given link and other places too.
Though now when I execute below:

```
select_single = {'date': "DATE_FORMAT(projectName_Modelname.created, '%%Y-%%m-%%d')"}
queryset.extra(select=select_single)
```

Following error comes:

```
DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'projectName_Modelname.created' in 'field list'")
```

where 'created' is Datetime field in Django model 'Modelname' of app 'projectName'

To debug when I replace `projectName_Modelname.created` with `NOW()` no error comes. I have also tried just `Modelname.created` instead of `projectName_Modelname.created` though with no benefit?

Note: I am using Django1.5.5

Comment: Django 1.5.5 has been obsolete for years. Hardly anyone even remembers how to use extra nowdays and last but not least, always try to use the same RDBMS in local and production to avoid exactly this sort of issue

Comment: And can you explain why you want to do this? It's much simpler to format the date on output, either in Python or in a template.

Comment: @e4c5 this is regarding a project I am maintaining and a request came to do some modifications.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If I couldn't manage to modify this, I will ultimately refactor the whole section

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like:

`date_raw_query = {'date': "date_format(created, '%%Y-%%m-%%d')"}`

and then try

`queryset.extra(select=date_raw_query)`

Hope that works in your setup. I have tried this on Django 1.7 and MySQL and seems to be working.

Also remember that if SQL errors start coming up, you can always do a `print queryset.extra(select=date_raw_query).query` to see what might be going wrong.

And when it comes to writing compatible code between SQLite and MySQL like this one, writing a custom MySQL function has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735955/1076075)

But I would suggest otherwise. It's better to have a similar dev environment with MySQL setup in local and also, upgrade Django as soon as possible. :P

Comment: I was getting `DatabaseError: (1052, "Column 'created' in field list is ambiguous")` on trying your suggestion. Though on analysing the MySQL queries, I found that modelname was changed to all lowercase but projectname was camelcase as it was(like projectName_modelname). Hence, I changed it to `projectName_modelname.created` and it worked! Thanks.